# Поменять направление блоков (из горизонтального в вертикальное)

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, sass

У меня есть сверстанный блок:

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="map" id="map">
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async
                src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A3b4851cc277917ecc11ea75bdc2a16e0839eb4494aa852c8b2162a19f79a0518&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=640&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false">
            </script>
        </div>
        <!-- /.map -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contacts-block">
                <div class="contacts">
                    <h3 class="contacts__title">Приезжайте к нам в гости!
                        Проконсультируем Вас
                        по всем вопросам ремонта
                    </h3>
                    <ul class="contacts-list">
                        <li class="contacts-list__item">
                            <span class="contacts-list__icon"><img src="img/footer/map-placeholder.png" alt=""></span>
                            <span class="contacts-list__text">г. Москва <br>
                                ул. Ленинга, д. 10,
                                корпус 2, оф. 308</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="contacts-list__item">
                            <span class="contacts-list__icon"><img src="img/footer/clock-with-white-face.png"
                                    alt=""></span>
                            <span class="contacts-list__text">Режим работы: <br>
                                с 9:00 до 18:00</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="contacts-list__item">
                            <span class="contacts-list__icon"><img src="img/footer/phone-call-button.png" alt="">
                            </span>
                            <span class="contacts-list__text">Телефон:<br>
                                <a href="tel: + 7(495)42-251-31 ">+ 7 (495) 42-251-31</a></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.contacts -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.contacts-block -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </footer>
    <!-- /.footer section -->
```

Стили распределены следующим образом:

```
.footer
    position: relative

.map
    position: absolute
    width: 50%
    top: 0
    left: 0

.contacts
    flex-basis: 50%
    padding-top: 100px
    padding-left: 200px
    &-block
        display: flex
        justify-content: flex-end
    &__title
        font-size: 24px
        line-height: 1.4
        +bold
        margin-bottom: 100px
    &-list
        list-style: none
        &__item
            display: flex
            align-items: flex-start
            margin-bottom: 39px
        &__icon
            text-align: center
            width: 20px
            height: 20px
            margin-right: 23px
```

Вот что из этого выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне заставить элементы располагаться вот таким образом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: flex-direction: column

Comment: Заверните оба блока во flex-контейнер и меняйте `flex-direction` когда нужно

Comment: @Neolot я карту не могу завернуть в контейнер, она должна быть с левого края страницы и так до середины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так, упростил и убрал лишнее:

**HTML**

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="map" id="map">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async
                src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A3b4851cc277917ecc11ea75bdc2a16e0839eb4494aa852c8b2162a19f79a0518&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=640&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false">
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- /.map -->
    <div class="contacts">
        <div class="contacts-list__content">
            <h3 class="contacts__title">Приезжайте к нам в гости! <br>
                Проконсультируем Вас
                по всем вопросам ремонта
            </h3>
            <ul class="contacts-list">
                <li class="contacts-list__item">
                    <span class="contacts-list__icon"><img src="img/footer/map-placeholder.png" alt=""></span>
                    <span class="contacts-list__text">г. Москва <br>
                            ул. Ленинга, д. 10, <br>
                            корпус 2, оф. 308</span>
                </li>
                <li class="contacts-list__item">
                        <span class="contacts-list__icon"><img src="img/footer/clock-with-white-face.png"
                                                               alt=""></span>
                    <span class="contacts-list__text">Режим работы: <br>
                            с 9:00 до 18:00</span>
                </li>
                <li class="contacts-list__item">
                        <span class="contacts-list__icon"><img src="img/footer/phone-call-button.png" alt="">
                        </span>
                    <span class="contacts-list__text">Телефон:<br>
                            <a href="tel: + 7(495)42-251-31 ">+ 7 (495) 42-251-31</a></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.contacts -->
</footer>
<!-- /.footer section -->
```

**SASS**

```
.footer
  display: flex

.map
  width: 50%

.contacts
  display: flex
  flex: 0 0 50%
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center

  &__title
    font-size: 24px
    line-height: 1.4
    +bold
    margin-bottom: 100px

  &-list
    list-style: none

    &__content
      padding: 100px

    &__item
      display: flex
      align-items: flex-start
      margin-bottom: 39px

      > span
        line-height: 19px

        > a
          text-decoration: none
          color: black

    &__icon
      text-align: center
      width: 20px
      height: 20px
      margin-right: 23px


@media (max-width: 768px)
  .footer
    flex-direction: column-reverse

  .map
    width: 100%

    &__title
      text-align: left
      font-size: 18px
      margin: 67px auto 30px

    &-list
      padding-left: 0
```

Comment: Да, об этом я тоже думал, но решил, что мой вариант мне больше по душе, так как контент у меня в контейнере. Если бы не было контейнера, я бы решил именно так. Вся сложность была в том, что надо было оставить контейнер

Comment: У вас блок на всю ширину, контейнер здесь не нужен

Comment: у меня секция на всю ширину, а контент у меня внутри контейнера, как и во всех остальных секциях в макете, просто здесь видно лишь часть

Comment: А, тогда просто положите контейнер внутрь `contacts`

Comment: как это? У меня контейнер 1170px на такой ширине, если я положу его внутрь contacts, то он у меня будет в итоге с середины и до правого края.
Или мне нужно контейнер другого размера положить?

Comment: Ладно, это обсуждение уже вышло за рамки вопроса

Comment: Я согласен, что не стоит это обсуждать, но просто вы дали решение, которое мне не подходит

Comment: Я ответил на ваш вопрос своим решением. Другое дело, я не могу учесть всех нюансов вашего проекта, так как вижу только часть его.

Comment: @shadow1337 Спасибо, что отметили мой ответ решением. Задавайте вопросы, если еще возникнут трудности.

Comment: да вам тоже спасибо, что помогли) буду))

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, что бы ваши элементы располагались таким образом только на ширине не больше 780px то оберните их вот так:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px){
.footer{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}


.map{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

Comment: К сожалению проблема именно в том, что карта должна быть на половину всей страницы, а не контейнера

Comment: А если так? .map{  width: 50%; }